# Would it be bad form to ask people to review your post history?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

I just had a random idea inspired from this [Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Code-examples-and-interviews.aspx)- would it be undesirable to create a discussion requesting from bored enough members to review your post history (**not** on SO itself, but maybe on Meta, or elsewhere)? I am curious if I ever ask too many "easy questions." I know I have a very high Q to A ratio, but I try my best to research my issues beforehand. I am also curious if anyone is capable of getting an impression of someone based on their post history (including how newbish they are). Of course, this would likely be a discouraged practice, as dozens of identical discussions going "plz giv me history review" would be both indistinguishable and annoying.

This is a dumb question, isn't it.

Comment: Don't voting and reputation already do this?

Comment: Not holistically (a post history in general, as opposed to individual questions).

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you just kind of ask?  :)

I don't know that there's such a thing as a question that's "too easy", though if you're not putting much research effort into trying to find your own answers then you'll forever be limited by the knowledge that others are willing to share.  You seem to (on Stack Overflow at least) put in a good level of effort up front, so you're not in this boat.

I also wouldn't worry about setting a precedent of asking for folks to look at your history, because I don't think it's something a lot of people will seek validation for, honestly.

And no, this isn't a dumb question, any time you put forth effort at trying to make the content as useful as possible on Stack Overflow, that's a Good Thing (tm)

Answer (score 1):

If you're self-aware enough to wonder about the quality of your questions, you're probably not in the same camp as your DailyWTF post. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want people to review your post history on programming questions, [there's an app for that](http://stackoverflow.com).

Nearly every single thing you've written has been reviewed by your peers in some form. Things have been voted down, hopefully you've learned something. Things have been voted up, hopefully you have *still* learned something.

Asking for people to review the things they have already reviewed is redundant, don't you think?